# Require user to login for certain pages

Tags: php, html

I have a mysql table that gets data inserted and deleted using the forms on my php pages. That all works. Now I want the users to be able to view index.php (homepage which displays the table and all its data) but if they click delete or add it must ask them to login before the add.php or delete.php pages are shown to them. I have written a login.php script below but am unsure how to force the page to check it before letting them through. Also if the user does login, will it take him to the page he clicked on or just back to index.php

**EDIT** Updated the Code As requested

login.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) && !empty($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'])) {


header("location:add.php"); // if user is logged in don't show the form take them were they need to be
} else {
?>


<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();        
    //Unset the variables stored in session
    unset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']);
    unset($_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']);
    unset($_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME']);
?>


<form name="loginform" action="login_exec.php" method="post">
<table width="309" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5">
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
    <!--the code bellow is used to display the message of the input validation-->
     <?php
        if( isset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && is_array($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && count($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) >0 ) {
        echo '<ul class="err">';
        foreach($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] as $msg) {
            echo '<li>',$msg,'</li>'; 
            }
        echo '</ul>';
        unset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']);
        }
    ?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="116"><div align="right">Username</div></td>
<td width="177"><input name="username" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right">Password</div></td>
<td><input name="password" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right"></div></td>
<td><input name="" type="submit" value="login" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>


<?php

}


?>
```

Login_exec.php

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Include database connection details
require_once('connection.php');

//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag
$errflag = false;

//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//Sanitize the POST values
$username = clean($_POST['username']);
$password = clean($_POST['password']);

//Input Validations
if($username == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($password == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
    $errflag = true;
}

//If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: login.php");
    exit();
}

//Create query
$qry="SELECT * FROM member WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        //Login Successful
        session_regenerate_id();
        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['mem_id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['username'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['password'];
        session_write_close();
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
    }else {
        //Login failed
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'user name and password not found';
        $errflag = true;
        if($errflag) {
            $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
            session_write_close();
            header("location: login.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
}else {
    die("Query failed");
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<center>
<html>
<head>
<title>Extension List</title></head><body>
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pwd = '****';

$database = 'list';
$table = 'users';

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
die("Can't select database");

// sending query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
if (!$result) {
die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
$field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
echo "<tr>";

// $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
// of $row to $cell variable
foreach($row as $cell)
    echo "<td>$cell</td>";

echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
<br>
<h1> Alpine Motors Extension List</h1>
<h2><a href="add.php">Add Extension</a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="delete.php"> Delete Extension</a></h2> 
<br> <br>
</h3>
</body>
</html>
</center>
<?php

}


?>
```

delete.php

```
<?php
```

require ("database.php");
    ?>

```
<?php


$this_Stud_ID =$_REQUEST['id'];

// sending query
mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '$this_Stud_ID'")
or die(mysql_error());      


if($_POST['action'])

header("Location: index.php");
?>
<center><form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['php_self'] ?>" method="post">
Enter ID Number :<br><input type="text" name="id"><br />
<br><input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete!">
<br> <br>
<h3>
<a href="index.php"> Main Menu </a> 
</h3>
</form>
</center>
```

Comment: Is it me or you don't protect passwords ?

Comment: its just a local webpage im testing. Not going to be tight on security for now

Comment: What's the problem? Whenever user will click ```add.php``` & ```delete.php``` check for USER"S SESSION  exist or not. If NOT then redirect user to LOGIN page & show the default content.

Comment: preparing queries and using `password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` and `password_verify($_POST['log_password'], $log_user['password'])` (for example) won't take you much time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on everypage that you need the user to login to access it you need to check if any of the sessions u set on login page are set and not empty

in this case I will use the member id session

**passwordProtectedPage.php**

```
<?php


if(isset( $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) && !empty($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'])):?>

    Do your html and other code

<?php

    else:

        header("location:page.php"); // take them to page

     //or echo "You not allowed to view this page <a href=\"login.php\">Please login</a>";

    endif;
    ?>
```

By the way you don't need to store error messages on session var, you could just do everything in one page if errors exists just print them back.

> Also it does not matter if its a local test page you need to do things
>   the correct way, so that you can be a better programmer one day, so
>   hash those passwords and read more about prepared statements.

**Edit :**

On the login page also first you need to check if the user is not logged in already. if they are loggedin take them to where they need to be else show the form and proccess.

```
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) && !empty($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'])) {


    header("location:page.php"); // if user is logged in don't show the form take them were they need to be
} else {
?>


    show the form content and do proccessing


<?php

}


?>
```

Comment: Will do about the security. Thank you

Comment: Will do sir il test it now give a few minutes ^^ Thank you very much im still learning but il get there

Comment: one question sir. if the user clicks add member and the login page opens and it picks up that he is logged in already. It will take him to add.php as long as i set header location correct? but what if he selects delete member? it will still take him to add.php if im correct?

Comment: When i click on login. it just takes me back to index.php and not to add.php sir

Comment: because `header("location: index.php");`  you specifed that it show take you there

Comment: what you need to is simple, you login the user on success take em to index.php then on index check the sessions then show the menu if when they click relevant link take them to tht page then check if they are logged in then take em to loggin if thy not

Comment: i see that in login_exec where //Login Successful. What would I need to change?

Comment: paste your updated code including the add.php  and other page @J.Hof

Comment: Done editing sir. I added delete.php but left out add.php because it's a lot of code and when i fix delete.php i will be able to fix add.php :)

Comment: your code is a mess are you on skype? if yes add me masivuyecokile2012 then we will go through the code.  @J.Hof

Comment: unfortunately i am at work and cant access skype now. but I will add you once I am home sir. Thank you

Comment: what can you chat on? emails? masivuyecokile@gmail.com